# count number of times each word in text file are used using python

Tags: python

Everyone, I'm new to Python and I got a text file that I would like to analyze and see how many times each word is used. I have been trying for a while but I get output of ex: `[('t', 1), ('i', 1), ('m', 1), ('e', 1), ('.', 1)]`. When I'm looking for output like: ('easy',5) etc.

Example of text in my text file:
"It is impossible to trust the information the company gives - even after they've confirmed that the payment has been taken and paid out (which already takes a week), they can come back to you and say it wasn't. They also refuse to take any responsibility for such cases. Nor do they help you with any chargebacks but just refer you to small claims court which is not really a good suggestion when you have quite a bit of customer with some abroad."

Thanks for your help!

Below is my current code:

```
   from nltk import FreqDist
   text = open('GC_review.txt')
   for word in text.read().split():
       fdist1 = FreqDist(word)
       print (fdist1.most_common(100))
```

Answer (score 3):

You following code:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dict = defaultdict(int)
>>> for word in test.split():
...     dict[word] += 1
... 
>>> print dict #defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'and': 2, 'already': 1, 'help': 1, 'just': 1, 'when': 1, 'is': 2, 'some': 1, 'back': 1, "they've": 1, 'really': 1, 'say': 1, 'customer': 1, 'have': 1, 'impossible': 1, 'trust': 1, '(which': 1, 'quite': 1, 'out': 1, 'even': 1, 'information': 1, 'confirmed': 1, 'court': 1, 'takes': 1, 'for': 1, 'also': 1, 'with': 2, '-': 1, 'been': 1, 'any': 2, 'to': 4, 'take': 1, 'They': 1, 'which': 1, 'taken': 1, 'you': 4, 'has': 1, 'cases.': 1, 'Nor': 1, 'gives': 1, 'do': 1, 'good': 1, 'week),': 1, 'that': 1, 'company': 1, 'after': 1, 'paid': 1, 'it': 1, 'abroad.': 1, 'but': 1, 'they': 2, 'not': 1, 'such': 1, 'bit': 1, 'chargebacks': 1, 'come': 1, 'payment': 1, 'a': 3, 'refuse': 1, "wasn't.": 1, 'of': 1, 'It': 1, 'responsibility': 1, 'can': 1, 'suggestion': 1, 'small': 1, 'claims': 1, 'the': 3, 'refer': 1})
```

I hope this will help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are counting letters in words instead of words in text. Change these lines:

```
for word in text.read().split():
   fdist1 = FreqDist(word)
```

to:

```
fdist1 = FreqDist(text.read().split())
```

No loop is needed.

Comment: DYZ awesomeee! damn should have asked for help earlier :D